# Add IIS 8.5 Custom Logging Fields with Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 allows for custom log fields with Enhanced Logging

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85

I want to add the fields with Powershell

The following works:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\siteName -name logfile.customFields.collection -value
 @{logFieldName='foo';sourceType='RequestHeader';sourceName='c-ip'}
```

But I cannot add a second entry to logfile.customFields.collection It requests -Force and overwrites the existing entry

I added 2 via the GUI to illustrate the issue

```
Get-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\siteName -name logfile.customFields.collection

logFieldName   : foo
sourceName     : c-ip
sourceType     : RequestHeader
Attributes     : {logFieldName, sourceName, sourceType}
ChildElements  : {}
ElementTagName : add
Methods        :
Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema

logFieldName   : foo2
sourceName     : c-servername
sourceType     : RequestHeader
Attributes     : {logFieldName, sourceName, sourceType}
ChildElements  : {}
ElementTagName : add
Methods        :
Schema         : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

logFieldName, sourceName, and sourceType are NoteProperty Members with the same name

How do I do this in Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user on the [IIS Forums](http://forums.iis.net/p/1205491/2064115.aspx?p=True&t=635210636290487692&pagenum=1) answered

```
   New-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\siteName -name logfile.customFields.collection -value
         @{logFieldName='foo';sourceType='RequestHeader';sourceName='c-ip'}

   New-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\siteName -name logfile.customFields.collection -value
         @{logFieldName='foo2';sourceType='RequestHeader';sourceName='c-ip'}
```

I confirmed this does work